# 3D Weapon Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started getting back into Unity and am learning how to use IEnumerator's. My script here isn't working at all. This script is supposed to clone a projectile out of a certain point, and continue firing (with a delay) until all "ammoLeftInClip" reaches zero. To which then another IEnumerator is called to reload the weapon based on "timeToReload".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    // variables
    [Header("Weapon")]
    public float fireRate = 0.5f;
    public float timeToReload = 3.5f;

    [Header("Ammo")]
    public float ammoLeftInClip = 0;
    public float clipAmount = 4;
    public float ammoInClips = 90;

    [Header("Bullet")]
    public GameObject projectile;

    private void Start()
    {
        ammoLeftInClip = ammoInClips;
        clipAmount--;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            print("IEnum 'fireWeapon' is being called");
            fireWeapon();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator fireWeapon()
    {
        if (ammoLeftInClip >= 1){
            print("Firing");
            var clone = Instantiate(projectile, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
            Destroy(clone, 5.0f);
            ammoLeftInClip--;
        } else if (ammoLeftInClip <= 0){
            print("reload() is being called");
            ammoLeftInClip = 0;
            reload();
        }
        print("IEnum 'fireWeapon' is being called");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
    }

    private void reload()
    {
        if (clipAmount >= 1)
        {
            print("IEnum 'reloadWeapon' is being called");
            reloadWeapon();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator reloadWeapon()
    {
        new WaitForSeconds(timeToReload);
        clipAmount--;
        yield return ammoLeftInClip = ammoInClips;
    }
}
```

Moving

```
if (ammoLeftInClip >= 1){
    print("Firing");
    var clone = Instantiate(projectile, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
    Destroy(clone, 5.0f);
    ammoLeftInClip--;
} else if (ammoLeftInClip <= 0){
    print("reload() is being called");
    ammoLeftInClip = 0;
    reload();
}
```

into a separate function allowed a projectile to be cloned out but nothing else worked.

Comment: are you forgetting a fireWeapon.MoveNext() call?  Did you put a break point in and see where execution is stopping?

Comment: use `StartCoroutine` to start the routines

Comment: StartCoroutine worked, thank you @hijinxbassist!

Answer (score 1):

This won't work like that of course for multiple reasons.

- [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are basically small temporary `Update` routines that get [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=net-8.0) called once a frame (or in other special occasions depending on the exact `yield` statements).

  However, in order to tell the Unity engine to do so you need to start coroutines by using [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

  If you don't then this basically equals a normal method call which will execute the `IEnumerator` until it reaches the first `yield` statement.
- even if you do the above the `IEnumerator`/Coroutine doesn't delay anything outside of it.

  => At best you will have multiple instances of it running in parallel .. your fireRate does nothing, you can simply spam the button and fire multiple times.
- unless you `yield return` the `IEnumerator` itself, a `yield` at the end of an `IEnumerator` is basically meaningless

Also the reload has multiple issues

- you create a new `WaitForSeconds` but do not yield it

  => this does nothing
- in the end you yield something that should rather be a simple statement instead

If you want to stick to coroutine you could do it like e.g.

```
// Special case: Unity will run this as Coroutine automatically 
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    ammoLeftInClip = ammoInClips;
    clipAmount--;

    // Ok as long as you yield somewhere inside 
    while(true)
    {
        // Could switch to GetKey in order to fire repeatedly while holding down the button 
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            yield return fireWeapon();
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            yield return reload();
        }
        // ! Without this block the while loop would be deadly !
        // this basically as a fallback yields at least one frame 
        else
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator fireWeapon()
{
    if(ammoLeftInClip >= 1)
    {
        print("Firing");
        var clone = Instantiate(projectile, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        Destroy(clone, 5.0f);
        ammoLeftInClip--;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return reload();
    } 

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
}

private IEnumerator reload()
{
    if (clipAmount >= 1)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToReload);
        clipAmount--;
        ammoLeftInClip = ammoInClips;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Might argue though that an `Update` and cooldown timer approach might be more appropriate but that's a matter of taste.

Above e.g. has the flaw that you can only react to the reload button when you finished waiting for the fire rate .. there are games where this is working different (e.g. shotgun in CounterStrike where you can reload right away after the last shot) so depends a lot on your exact desired behavior